Error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression when using parenthesis around query
I have the below query (that is actually used as a derived table for a larger query set) that when I run the below query with the outer parenthesis I am getting the ORA-00979 error, however if I run the query without the outer parenthesis it runs fine.
            (  SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                      ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,                         
                      TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) COST_DATE,
                      to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
                  FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                       CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                       CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                 WHERE 1=1
                   AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                   AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID
               
                   AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                   AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                   AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID          

                GROUP BY  A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                          ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE
                          ,to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90')
                    
              ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST  )


I doubt, if ORDER BY clause is supported in subqueries

Might be better to use a CTE in this case

No matter what the real issue is. When dealing with such old queries, the first thing I do is re-write them using up-to-date explicit join syntax ([INNER] JOIN ... ON|USING etc.) that we have been using in the last decades. Then I'd clean up the code a little, like having the commas either in front of the line or the end, switching to lowercase, using mnemonic aliases (like tld for tax layer details rather than c). That last step would probably have helped me spot the error with the alias, as explained in kfinity's answer...

... Or, more likely, I'd have removed the superfluous ORDER BY clause and thus got rid of the problem altogether. I suppose that you can remove the TO_CHAR, too, and rather work with dates and numbers. If you can't, this can be an indicator for an inappropriate data model.


however if I run the query without the outer parenthesis it runs fine

I really doubt that. Here's a simplified reproducible example of the issue with your query, using the all_objects table:
select o.owner, max(o.object_id) as object_id
from all_objects o
group by o.owner
order by o.object_id;

This returns not a GROUP BY expression because o.object_id refers to the table column, not column 2 in the selected output.
If you just remove the table alias from the last line, it works fine, because now object_id is referring to column 2 in the results:
select o.owner, max(o.object_id) as object_id
from all_objects o
group by o.owner
order by object_id;

In your example, you should remove the B. from B.COST_DATE, changing the last line to:
ORDER BY COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST  )

And as Thorsten mentioned in the comments, it's a good practice to avoid creating column aliases with the same name as a column in the table, just to avoid confusion:
SELECT ...
TO_CHAR(MAX(B.COST_DATE)) MAX_COST_DATE,
...
ORDER BY MAX_COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST


Well spotted and equally well explained. Ordering by date strings ('dd/mm/yyyy'? 'mm/dd/yyyy'?) is unlikely to be desired, though. But well, in a subquery the ORDER BY is superfluous and can hence be removed, anyway :-)
